# Creating a list of prime numbers up to a given n value in SML

Tags: recursion, sml

I've very recently started learning SML, and for an assignment am tasked with creating a list of prime numbers up to a user inputted n value. I've been stuck for a few hours playing around with different possible solutions, and am currently here, with a subscript out of bounds error:

```
fun primes(n) = 
let
  val lst = tl(makeLst(n))
  val k = 0
  fun recurse(lst,k) = 
    if k > n then lst
    else recurse(removeMult(lst, List.nth(lst,k)), k+1)
in
  recurse(lst,k)
end;
```

I believe that the error is coming from my use of List.nth(), though i'm not sure of another way to get the index needed for the removeMult function. Any help would be very appreciated!! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The argument list becomes shorter during the recursion in `recurse`, so of course you get a failure if try to run up to `n`. The trick is not to recurse up to some `n` but until the you have reached the end of the list.

There is another problem here: you start `recurse` with 0. Everything is a multiple of 1, so in fact, the list will get empty on the second recursion.

Finally, your `makeLst` function, while semantically correct, is inefficient. Appending at the and of a list has to copy the whole list. You should try to extend the list at its start. Otherwise the function has quadratic complexity.

Here is how I would write this code:

```
fun enum (n, m) = if n > m then [] else n :: enum (n+1, m)
fun sieve [] = []
  | sieve (n::ns) = n :: sieve (List.filter (fn m => m mod n > 0) ns)
fun primes n = sieve (enum (2, n))
```

Comment: `fun enum (n, m) = List.tabulate (m - n + 1, fn i => i + n)`